# Adding items to existing list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list as below:

```
List<Teacher> _teacher= new List<Teacher>();
```

Teacher has below fields :

```
public class Teacher
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string age{ get; set; }
    public string basic{ get; set; }
    public string hra{ get; set; }

   }
```

Another list as below:

```
List<Salary> _salary= new List<Salary>();
```

Salary has below fields :

```
public class Salary
{
    public string basic{ get; set; }
    public string hra{ get; set; }
}
```

In a particular condition ,List Teacher is being populated with name and age only.I need to populate the basic and hra in teacher list from the salary list.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should improve the naming conventio too :)

Comment: Additional points tp your questions

1. I think that age should be int.

2. basic and hra should be int as well.

Comment: I guess anything with Salary (Money related) it gotta be `decimal`

Comment: its just not clear.Are you saying each salary on SalaryList belong to a teacher on the teacher list.in tht case how do you map the salary without any sort of dictionary datastructure

Answer (score 2):

```
 salary.AddRange(teachers.Select(s=>new Salary{Basic=s.Basic, hra=s.hra}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have given the variables as an example in my question. I have tried salary.AddRange(teachers.Select(s=>new Salary{Basic=s.Basic, hra=s.hra})); in my program. But it is appending the salary details as another item in the teacher list. My requirement is to add salary details in existing items in teacher list. Hope my question is clear.Please guide me on this
Example :
Teacher list :
alice,30
Antony,35
Sunil,40

Now I need to have the list as :adding salary components also
alice,30,5000,2000
Antony,35,6000,3000
Sunil,40,7000,2500

Comment: @Soumya, You should edit your question with content of this comment. My attempt to answer was apparently almost opposite of what you wanted (my line collects salary info from all teachers). Also when editing the question please make clear how these 2 lists are related to each other... and please *don't* name variable with random letters in public samples - if you can come up with decent name use something generic like ValueX.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a list of `Teacher` and a list of `Salary` and you need to push in the details of the salary to the relevant fields of the `Teacher` class.

I think you can achieve this by looping through the Teacher class and then access the Salary list at that particular index and then assign those values. (i hope the count of both the list are same else you will need some way of identifying how to map those values)

something on these lines

```
for (int indx = 0; indx < lstdevelop.Count; indx++)
{
     lstTeacher[indx].Basic = lstSalary[indx].Basic;
     //
}
```

Also it would be better to use the right Datatypes rather than having all of them as `string`, money related things stick to `decimal`

Comment: +1... also it is absolutely unclear how Teacher element corresponds to Salary, so you approach by using the same indexes is most reasonable for current version of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have used string as an example in the question.Actually I am using float for money related variables in my program as the exisitng database has float as datatype.Does it make any difference from using decimal datatype?

Comment: Thanks Alexei for the reply.
My requirement is to populate a radgrid with a list.First time the radgrid is binded with list (as I told in my example as Teacher which has all the fileds in my grid) in needsource event.
Secondly on clicking a button,I need to update some columns with some calculated values (eg :hra,basic) in the grid.

Comment: ----Continuation to above comment--- So to accomplish this,I was storing the list of data, binding to grid in needsource event, to a session variable .on button click,I was trying to create another list with calculated values for each grid column.So in this case I think count of items in both list will be the same.Correct me if I am wrong. Finally I need to push in the values from second list to the relevant fields of first list and bind the grid with final list(which will be teacher list will all the fields).

Answer (score 0):

may be you can set their salary based on teacher level like this

```
    List _teacher = new List();
    List _salary = new List();

    //populate salaries for later used
    _salary.Add(new Salary { basic = "300", hra = "400", level = "1" });
    _salary.Add(new Salary { basic = "500", hra = "700", level = "2" });

    _teacher.Add(new Teacher { 
        name = "Teacher 1",
        age = "34",
        level = "1",
        basic = _salary.Single(p=>p.level == "1").basic, //set basic and hra based on teacher's level
        hra = _salary.Single(p=>p.level == "1").hra,
    });

    _teacher.Add(new Teacher
    {
        name = "Teacher 2",
        age = "47",
        level = "2",
        basic = _salary.Single(p => p.level == "2").basic, //set basic and hra based on teacher's level
        hra = _salary.Single(p => p.level == "2").hra,
    });

    foreach (Teacher t in _teacher)
        Console.WriteLine(t.name + ", "+t.age + ", " +t.basic + ", " + t.hra);
```